# Drools for rating telco records

Tags: drools, billing

Has anyone successfully used Drools as a kind of "rating engine" before? What are your experiences?

I'm trying to process a couple of millions of records (of slightly different types) and apply rating/pricing to these records.

Rating would be based of tables or database lookups as well as chains of if/then/else/else/else/else conditions using the lookup data.

Traditional rating engines don't employ rule mechanisms in ways that I'm comfortable with...

thanks for your help

Comment: If the answer is "yes": what would it tell you?

Comment: I edited the question -> "successfully used"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide a slightly more informative response (although your question can't be *answered* based on the very vague description you've given), your "rating" is just one of the many names for what I use to call "classification problem". It has been solved many times using Drools.

However, this doesn't mean to say that *your* problem, with its particular environmental flavour and expected performance (how *fast* do you want to have the 2M records processed?) can be solved *best* using Drools - especially when the measure for deciding the quality isn't settled. (For instance: Is ease of maintenance more important than top efficiency?)

Go ahead and rig up a prototype and run a test to see how it goes. That will give you a more reliable answer than anything else. If someone says that something similar couldn't be done, it could be due to bad rule coding. If someone says that something similar was done successfully, it may not have had one of the quirks of your setup. And so on.

Comment: your points are all valid. it's hard to provide numbers, though, because throughput speed depends on the complexity of the rules, the structure of the data etc etc. Of course we will set up a prototype and test it with our data. What I have seen in a number of products is, that rule engines have been *removed* from these products. That doesn't give me a very positive impression...

Comment: "Throughput speed depends on the complexity of the rules" - yes, but not the same way as procedural code depends on its cyclomatic complexity. --- It's easier to write poorly performing code in Drools than in any other programming system I know, and on the last count I was bypassing 25. --- Many people are led to believe that an RBS is some sort of silver bullet, but that it just isn't. --- Although, using an RBS until you've settled the specs with the users with the intent of migrating on to procedural code could be a design decision that may have its merits. It depends on many factors...

Comment: We're coming from procedural code right now and it's just too hard too maintain the business rules in all that code. That is the reason why RBS are being considered. Complexity is more or less arbitrary up to a certain limit. Think if/then/else/else/n-th else cascades.

Comment: These if/then/else/else/n-th else cascades can be tricky. Finally, you might consult my https://engage.redhat.com/forms/rule-design-patterns although I don't know whether it covers your use case.